# Composer fail on update with "npm-signature" error

Tags: npm, yii2, composer-php

While updating my [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) application libraries by `composer update` command, [composer-php](/questions/tagged/composer-php) exited with

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                          
Unknown downloader type: npm-signature. Available types: git, svn, fossil, hg, perforce, zip, rar, tar, gzip, xz, phar, file, path.  

Exception trace:
() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/DownloadManager.php:128
Composer\Downloader\DownloadManager->getDownloader() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/DownloadManager.php:152
Composer\Downloader\DownloadManager->getDownloaderForInstalledPackage() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/DownloadManager.php:211
Composer\Downloader\DownloadManager->download() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:186
Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->installCode() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:90
Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->install() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:173
Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->install() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:160
Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:588
Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:227
Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:161
Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:242
Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:842
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:251
Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:100
Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:58
require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:24
```

Until yesterday everything worked as expected on my local develop environment.

Today, while pushing some updates, both staging and develop (who has no changes compared to the yesterday update) exit with the above error.

This is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
"name": "name/project",
"description": "Project",
"keywords": ["tags..."],
"homepage": "http://web.myaddress.yes/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
    "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": ">2",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "^3.4",
    "kartik-v/yii2-helpers": "^1.3",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform": "^1.4",
    "kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol": "^1.9",
    "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "^1.7",
    "kartik-v/yii2-dropdown-x": "^1.2",
    "kartik-v/yii2-dialog": "^1.0",
    "kidzen/yii2-dynamicform": "^2",
    "kartik-v/yii2-tabs-x": "^1.2",
    "rmrevin/yii2-ionicon": "^1.2",
    "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "^1.6",
    "kartik-v/php-date-formatter": "^1.3",
    "kartik-v/yii2-export": "^1.2",
    "webtoucher/yii2-js-cookie": "^1.0",
    "lajax/yii2-translate-manager": "~1.7",
    "mdmsoft/yii2-admin": "~2.0",
    "elvenpath/yii2-eu-vatvalidator": "^1.1",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "2.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-slider": "^1",
    "edofre/yii2-fullcalendar-scheduler": "1.1.x-dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
]
}
```

Is there something strange here or maybe a problem NPM server side?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### UPDATE

This bug was fixed in the [last release](https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin/releases/tag/v1.4.3) of `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`, upgrade should fix the issue:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.4.3"
```

Asset-packagist was also [fixed](https://github.com/hiqdev/asset-packagist/issues/80#issuecomment-391290424).

---

This is `fxpio/composer-asset-plugin` [bug](https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin/issues/321). Seems like npm introduced a [new feature into `dist` info](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/172999548390/new-pgp-machinery), and this breaks plugin which converts npm packages to composer packages. So every package which use this new feature, will not be able to install via composer.

I don't known any easy workaround, you need to wait until bug gets fixed. But if you can not wait, you can try locate problematic package and define it manually in your `composer.json`.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "npm-asset/moment",
            "version": "2.22.0",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://registry.npmjs.org/moment/-/moment-2.22.0.tgz",
                "type": "tar"
            }
        }
    }
    ...
],
```

Comment: Yes, my problem is related to [fullcalendar-scheduler](https://github.com/Edofre/yii2-fullcalendar-scheduler) that depends on **fullcalendar**, who depends on **jquery** and **moment.js**. Is there any way to configure `"repositories":` to include all of them and bypass that plugin breaking change? I'm not a composer or npm expert...

Comment: @letsjump I don't know any simple way. You could switch to `composer-asset-plugin` and patch it locally (there is a PR with fix).

Comment: The problem is not in fxpio/composer-asset-plugin - it's actually composer's native error at src/Composer/Downloader/DownloadManager.php:128 and it also happens using https://asset-packagist.org

Comment: @Swayok asset-packagist uses `fxpio/composer-asset-plugin` internally. And composer throws this error because `fxpio/composer-asset-plugin`/asset-packagist gives incorrect package info. There is nothing wrong with composer here.

Answer (score 6):

Another workaround is to use the bower-asset/ instead of npm-asset.

I was able to switch all of my npm-asset packages to bower-asset and it worked perfectly.

Caution: be sure the version numbers match up.

Comment: Actually you should stick to `bower-assets` whenever possible - `npm` repository is a real mess and using it as a source of packages for composer will be a constant source of problems. Unfortunately this is not always possible - bower was deprecated and many packages no longer supports bower.

Answer (score 4):

Finally the problem has been solved by:

1. removed the indicted *edofree/fullcalendar-scheduler* extension
2. manually added its dependences directly in my composer.json giving the version number required by the extension

   - npm-asset/moment
   - npm-asset/jquery
   - npm-asset/fullcalendar
3. reinstalled *edofree/fullcalendar-scheduler* by composer command `composer require`

Here there is the resulted composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "myapp name",
...,
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    ...,
    "bower-asset/moment": "V2.22.0",
    "bower-asset/jquery": "V3.3.1",
    "bower-asset/fullcalendar": "V3.8.0",
    "edofre/yii2-fullcalendar-scheduler": "V1.1.12"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
]
}
```

I think the goal was to install the assets required by the plugin *before* the plugin itself

**Note:** My Yii2 was installed without `composer-asset-plugin`

Comment: "install the assets required by the plugin before the plugin itself" -> This also worked for me for the philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar extension.